# Trouble selecting some JSON data with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing

I created a simple Component where I organize names, however I have troubles getting the names in my JSON file.

Here is what my JSON file looks like

```json
{
  "tasks" : [
    { 
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "Studies", 
      "status": "Completed", 
      "progress": 100
    },
    { 
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "Writing",
      "status": "In Progress", 
      "progress": 91
    }
  ]
}
```

And the function in my React Component

```js
function orderA() {
  data.tasks.map((t) => 
    console.log(t.name)
  );
  const noms = data.tasks.name;
  noms.sort();
  console.log(noms);
}
```

I call the function by clicking on a button, `console.log(t.name)` show the names I need to use but `data.tasks.name` gives me an undefined error but if I put names in my const my function is working.

Comment: I'd like to note that where you're doing `data.tasks.map(t => console.log(t.name))`, you should rather use `data.tasks.forEach(t => console.log(t.name))`. The result is the same, but the `.map`-function is meant for tranforming data in an array, while the `.forEach`-function is meant for doing an operation (or several) on every item in an array (like you're doing). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to acces the names inside the loop, because `data.tasks` is an array :

```
orderA() {
  const noms = data.tasks.map((t) => t.name).sort();
  console.log(noms);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you set the `noms` variable you're accesing to `tasks` which is an array. And you're referencing the complete `tasks` array that does not have a `name` attribute.

You'll need to iterate through the `tasks` array or to select an specific position of the array, and then access the `name` attribute of the object in that position of the array.

Example: `data.tasks[0].name`.